# StructType can not accept object?

Tags: pyspark

How do I resolve this issue?

```
rdd.collect()  //['3e866d48b59e8ac8aece79597df9fb4c'...]

rdd.toDF()    //Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>

myschema=StructType([StructField("col1", StringType(),True)])
rdd.toDF(myschema).show()
```

// StructType can not accept object "3e866d48b59e8ac8aece79597df9fb4c" in type

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you have:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['3e866d48b59e8ac8aece79597df9fb4c'])
```

Which is a one dimensional data structure, a data frame is 2d; `map` each number to a tuple solves the problem:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x,)).toDF().show()
+--------------------+
|                  _1|
+--------------------+
|3e866d48b59e8ac8a...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Aha!, that is!!