# pyspark createDataframe typeerror: structtype can not accept object 'id' in type <class 'str'>

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

An API call is returning DICT type response similar to the output below:

> {'Account': {'id': 123, 'externalIdentifier': None, 'name':
> 'test acct', 'accountNumber': None, 'Rep': None,
> 'organizationId': 123, 'streetAddress': '123 Main Road',
> 'streetAddressCity': 'Town City', 'streetAddressState': 'Texas',
> 'streetAddressZipCode': '76123', 'contact': [{'id': 10001, 'name':
> 'Test test', 'extID': '9999999999'}]}}

I am attempting to build a dataframe of the ***Account*** record returned but I keep getting   *TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'id' in type <class 'str'>*. I have tried the other methods which include adding .item(), [map lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927044/structtype-can-not-accept-object) and [converting types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676594/spark-sql-typeerrorstructtype-can-not-accept-object-in-type-s-typeobj), but always coming back to the same error.

```
account_schema = StructType([
StructField('id', StringType(), True),
StructField('externalIdentifier', StringType(), True),
StructField('name', StringType(), True),
StructField('Account_number', StringType(), True),    
StructField('Rep', StructType([
    StructField('firstName', StringType(), True),
    StructField('lastName', StringType(), True),
    StructField('email', StringType(), True),
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
])),
StructField('streetAddress', StringType(), True),   
StructField('streetAddressCity', StringType(), True),   
StructField('streetAddressState', StringType(), True),   
StructField('streetAddressZipCode', StringType(), True)  ])


df = spark.createDataFrame(account_response['Account'], schema=account_schema)
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the data type of `data` argument should be RDD or some kind of iterable like list, array etc. as per [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame.html).

If you enclose your data in square brackets then you get a spark dataframe with one record.

```py
spark.createDataFrame(data=[account_response['Account']], schema=account_schema)
```

Full working example:

```py
account_response = {'Account': {'id': 123, 'externalIdentifier': None, 'name': 'test acct', 'accountNumber': None, 'Rep': None, 'organizationId': 123, 'streetAddress': '123 Main Road', 'streetAddressCity': 'Town City', 'streetAddressState': 'Texas', 'streetAddressZipCode': '76123', 'contact': [{'id': 10001, 'name': 'Test test', 'extID': '9999999999'}]}}

account_schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('externalIdentifier', StringType(), True),
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('Account_number', StringType(), True),    
    StructField('Rep', StructType([
        StructField('firstName', StringType(), True),
        StructField('lastName', StringType(), True),
        StructField('email', StringType(), True),
        StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    ])),
    StructField('streetAddress', StringType(), True),   
    StructField('streetAddressCity', StringType(), True),   
    StructField('streetAddressState', StringType(), True),   
    StructField('streetAddressZipCode', StringType(), True)  
])


df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[account_response['Account']], schema=account_schema)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------+---------+--------------+----+-------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|id |externalIdentifier|name     |Account_number|Rep |streetAddress|streetAddressCity|streetAddressState|streetAddressZipCode|
+---+------------------+---------+--------------+----+-------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|123|null              |test acct|null          |null|123 Main Road|Town City        |Texas             |76123               |
+---+------------------+---------+--------------+----+-------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
```